# whats wrong with this postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I made this postgresql function but im getting this error:

> ERROR:  no existe el cursor «cur_1»
> CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL ganancias(text) en la línea 11 en FETCH
> SQL state: 34000

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ganancias(p_jugador text) RETURNS Integer AS
$$
DECLARE
reg1          RECORD;
reg2          RECORD;
cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(id_mano) FROM movimientos where 
nombre_jugador=p_jugador;
cur_2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM movimientos where  id_mano = reg1.id_mano 
and linea =(select min(linea) from movimientos where 
id_mano=reg1.id_mano);
v_cont INTEGER =0;
v_contAux INTEGER=0;
BEGIN
 OPEN cur_1;
 LOOP
  FETCH cur_1 INTO reg1;
  EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

OPEN cur_2;
LOOP
     FETCH cur_2 INTO reg2;
     EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    v_cont=reg2.stack;
    v_cont= v_cont - v_contAux;
    v_contAux=reg2.stack;

 END LOOP;
 CLOSE cur_1;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE cur_2;

RETURN v_cont;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0):

`cur_2` is a cursor variable in PL/pgSQL, and you cannot use it in the SQL command `FETCH` without knowing the name of the cursor itself. This is confusing, and I cannot explain it better without describing a lot of internal information.

Suffice it to say that you do not use `FETCH` in PL/pgSQL. This is the way to go:

```
DECLARE
   reg1 record;
BEGIN
   FOR reg1 IN
      SELECT DISTINCT(id_mano) FROM movimientos
      WHERE nombre_jugador=p_jugador
   LOOP
      /* handle the row */
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I am sure that what you are trying to do can be expressed more efficiently than with nested cursor loops.